# Sed in httpd.conf only for only one <VirtualHost>

Tags: linux, sed, apache-httpd

I have a httpd.conf file containing the following virtual hosts :

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
JkMount /soncn/* tomcat3
SSLProtocol -all +TLSv1
SSLCipherSuite RSA:!LOW:!EXP:!eNULL:!aNULL:!RC4
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile bla
SSLCertificateKeyFile  bla
RewriteEngine On
RewriteOptions Inherit
ServerName dionisos
</VirtualHost>
SSLSessionCache  dbm:/opt/apache/logs/ssl_gcache_data
<VirtualHost *:8443>
SSLProtocol -all +TLSv1
SSLCipherSuite RSA:!LOW:!EXP:!eNULL:!aNULL:!RC4
SSLEngine on 
SSLCertificateFile bla
SSLCertificateKeyFile  bla
RewriteEngine On
RewriteOptions Inherit
ServerName dionisos
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On
PerlModule CSA_Filter
<Proxy *>
Require all granted
</Proxy>
ProxyPass / ajp://162.237.187.150:8012/
ProxyPassReverse / ajp://162.237.185.150:8012/
ProxyTimeout 3600
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:8191>
SSLProtocol -all +TLSv1
SSLCipherSuite RSA:!LOW:!EXP:!eNULL:!aNULL:!RC4
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile bla
SSLCertificateKeyFile  bla
RewriteEngine On
RewriteOptions Inherit
ServerName dionisos
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On
PerlModule CSA_Filter
<Proxy *>
Require all granted
</Proxy>
ProxyPass / ajp://bla:8010/
ProxyPassReverse / ajp://bla:8010/
ProxyTimeout 3600
</VirtualHost>
```

I want to insert the following lines only for VirtualHost *:443 :

```
<Proxy *>
Require all granted
</Proxy>
ProxyPass /App https://servername:8080/App/
ProxyPassReverse /App https://servername:8080/App/
```

I had a lot of tries but could not find the proper sed :

```
cat httpd.conf|tr '\n' '^'|sed 's#\(<VirtualHost \*:443>.*ServerName dionisos\)#\1 \n<Proxy *>\nRequire all granted\n</Proxy>\nProxyPass /App https://servername:8080/App/\nProxyPassReverse /Wibox https://servername:8080/App/ \n#g'|tr '^' '\n' > httpd.conf.updated
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU sed and GNU bash:

Put new lines in a file (insert.txt).

```
sed '/^<VirtualHost \*:443>/r insert.txt' httpd.conf
```

or use stdin:

```
echo -e 'lines\nto\ninsert' | sed '/^<VirtualHost \*:443>/r /dev/stdin' httpd.conf
```

If you want to edit your httpd.conf "in place" use sed's option `-i`.